# Is it OK to use a static member in an IntentService to facilitate passing received data to an Activity?

Tags: android

I have class that extends 'IntentService' - this class occasionally receives data from a server, and when it does I need to pass this data to the current running Activity.

To achieve this, I've added a static instance of my Activity to the IntentService, along with a `registerRecipient` method that the Activity calls, passing in `self`.  When the IntentService gets a message from the server, it just calls the appropriate notification method on its static instance of the Activity (in which I set an `EditText` view's text property via `runOnUiThread`).

Aside from the general problem of using static variables instead of instances, is this a sound way to do this?  One of my colleagues suggested that this static instance is still subject to being garbage-collected, which would hose the whole scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this scenario you do not need a static member variable of your `Activity`. What you need is a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which corresponds with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253223/whats-the-right-way-to-send-messages-from-my-intentservice-back-to-an-activity/5253260#5253260) question.

Comment: I almost gave the check to Octavian instead, purely on the basis of your Charlie Sheen pic.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Ouch, not winning style! :-(

Answer (score 1):

You could also fire off and `Intent` from the `IntentService` and handle the `Intent` in the receiving `Activity`.